# how can I commit changes to a bzr branch from within emacs?

Tags: emacs, bazaar

I do most development from within emacs, and I use bzr for version control. I infer that <kbd>c-x v =</kbd> is equivalent to bzr diff, but it is not clear to me how I can make commits from within emacs, or how various bzr commands map to emacs key bindings. Can anyone suggest the best approach or point me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bazaar `bzr` command is one of the backend tool managed by VC. Thus you can use all your VC commands to use the bzr backend :

```
C-x v +     vc-update
C-x v =     ediff-revision
C-x v D     vc-root-diff
C-x v L     vc-print-root-log
C-x v a     vc-update-change-log
C-x v b     vc-switch-backend
C-x v c     vc-rollback
C-x v d     vc-dir
C-x v g     vc-annotate
C-x v h     vc-insert-headers
C-x v i     vc-register
C-x v l     vc-print-log
C-x v m     vc-merge
C-x v r     vc-retrieve-tag
C-x v s     vc-create-tag
C-x v u     vc-revert
C-x v v     vc-next-action
C-x v ~     vc-revision-other-window
```

I've configured <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> to call ediff-revision using the following command in my .emacs :

```
(eval-after-load "vc-hooks"
         '(define-key vc-prefix-map "=" 'ediff-revision))
```

Comment: érôme: Thanks for the list of VC commands. Is the list something that emacs can generate (with a simple command) or did you have to build it by hand?

Comment: C-h b   to list all keybindings of the current mode of the buffer you're currently in.

Comment: érôme: I can't believe how long I've gone without knowing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>C-x v v</kbd>, or `vc-next-action`.  Take a look at the [VC section](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html#Version-Control) in the emacs manual

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [DVC mode](http://gds.gsfc.nasa.gov/dvc-intro.html) is what you're after. Sorry, I haven't used it, so I can't tell you anything about it.